# Does Active Data Guard include Golden Gate?

Tags: oracle

I've been told that Active Data Guard incorporates Golden Gate as part of its technology stack.

Is Golden Gate usable directly from the Active Data Guard installation?

Answer (score 2):

It's the other way around. Active Data Guard is included if you license GoldenGate on Oracle Database Enterprise Edition.

The [GoldenGate product page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html) on Oracle Technology Network states:

> The license for Oracle GoldenGate includes a full use license for
>   Oracle Active Data Guard, and a full use license for XStream in the
>   Oracle Database.

Comment: Can you provide any link that support this claim?

Comment: I have added a quote and link, as per your request.

Answer (score 1):

They are separate things, but it's best to read this White Paper to get a better understanding of how each work both individually, and together: [Oracle Active Data Guard 
Real-Time Data Protection and Availability](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/availability/active-data-guard-wp-12c-1896127.pdf).

Downloads available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/downloads/index.html).

Note that Golden Gate has replaced Oracle Streams as of Oracle 12.